# @media Queries - css repeat not rendering

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hope someone can advice please

Have an issue getting my footer-wrap to repeat on tablet devices in landscape mode (480px)

HTML

```
<div id="footer-wrap">
    <footer class="footer-inner">
        <section class="foo1">
            <h1>Get in Touch</h1>
            <hr>
        </section>
    </footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#footer-wrap {
  background: none repeat #373737;
  min-height: 400px; }

.footer-inner {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto; }
```

Within the Head I have

Initially I didn't target the #footer-wrap within the media query as I assumed that as it just contained the BG colour and no other attribute, pulling from the main stylesheet would suffice

I have tried adding within the Media Query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){

    #footer-wrap {
            width: 100%; /*with the intention of just filling the div*/
         }
    }
```

Also tried

```
#footer-wrap {
        width:767px;
    background: none repeat #373737;
     }
```

Neither have worked

Can anyone advice, I am sure the answer is hitting me between the eyes, but I cant for the live of me figure it out, and as it is I am running behind on this project

Many thanks in advance

John

Comment: `background: none repeat...` There's nothing to repeat there.

Comment: The repeat attribute will repeat a background image. You don't have a background image specified.

Comment: Issue resolved, thanks for pointing out I never added the bloody image .... I need a break !

Kind Regards and thanks again

John

Answer (score 0):

In the media queries :-

```
@media (max-width: 767px){

#footer-wrap{

margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: -20px;
```

}
}

Comment: Yes, yes, all haste on my behalf, I did say I was behind, my apologies, I told you it was hitting me in the eyes.

Thanks for pointing out , issue resolved, we will move on and I will waste no one elses time

Cheers guys

Regards

J

Answer (score 0):

I thought i might add how this was fully resolved, if not for closure, but maybe might help someone else

The footer container needed min-width 100%

That was all ... 3 bloody hours, and that's all it needed

Might help someone else who was as bewildered as I was

Issue resolved fully and complete

R

John